# Build error when attempting to use cesium with Angular CLI (v7)

Tags: angular, angular-cli, cesiumjs, angular-cli-v7

I have just started working with `angular-cesium` and am following their [getting started](https://github.com/articodeltd/angular-cesium#getting-started) guide for setting up with the angular CLI. On attempting to serve my application, I am am encountering the follow error:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/cesium/index.js 9:4
Module parse failed: 'return' outside of function (9:4)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
|     module.exports = require(path.join(__dirname, 'Build/Cesium/Cesium'));
>     return;
| }
|
```

The contents of the `index.js` file for cesium is:

```
'use strict';

var path = require('path');

// If in 'production' mode, use the combined/minified/optimized version of Cesium
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    module.exports = require(path.join(__dirname, 'Build/Cesium/Cesium'));
    return;
}

// Otherwise, use un-optimized requirejs modules for improved error checking. For example 'development' mode
var requirejs = require('requirejs');
requirejs.config({
    paths: {
        'Cesium': path.join(__dirname, 'Source')
    },
    nodeRequire: require
});

module.exports = requirejs('Cesium/Cesium');
```

I can't see where there is a `return` outside of a function as per the error I am getting.

What could be going on here to explain the reason behind this error?

I have sample repo here, where this error can be replicated -> https://github.com/parky128/cesium-playground

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your tsconfig.json, add a line in your paths section:

```
"cesium": ["node_modules/cesium/Build/Cesium/Cesium.js"]
```

This will tell it to look at the 'correct' cesium file instead of the one that is expecting to be ran directing from node (from my understanding)

Note: You could also point to the Build/CesiumUnminified if you prefer